# Callback without parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback

I have a nodejs code that has callback and I couldn't understand how it works. Can someone explain it

```
function readJSONIntoArray(directory, array, callback) 
{
    var ending = 'json';
    fs.readdir(directory, function (err, files) 
    {
        if (err)
           throw err;
        var fileCnt = files.length;
        files.forEach(function (file) 
        {
            if (endsWith(file, '.' + ending)) 
            {
                file = file.substring(0, file.length - (ending.length + 1));
                var fileContent = require(path.join(directory, file));
                array.push(fileContent);
                log.info('Read file: ' + file);
            }
            fileCnt--;
            if (fileCnt === 0 && typeof callback === 'function') 
            {
                callback();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Here the callback is empty so I guess no value is being returned. But in actual output the array is returned. I couldn't understand an empty callback can return a array.

Function call:`readJSONIntoArray(profilefolder, profiles, setProfileDescriptions);`

Definition of setProfileDescriptions is separate.

```
function setProfileDescriptions() 
{
    profiles = bubblesort(profiles, 'order');
}
```

Inside the `setProfileDescriptions` the profile array is populated with the json data from the file read in the read function.
Can someone explain how the 3rd argument in the `readJSONIntoArray` function call is recognized as a function and the array profiles is returned?

Comment: profiles is not given to `setProfileDescription` as a parameter. However the variable might be global, if so you can access it because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var globalArray=[];
function readFunction(path,globalArray,callbackFunction){
    globalArray.push(path);
    callbackFunction();
}
function callbackFunction(){
    //globalArray was global so i can call here
    console.log(globalArray);
}

readFunction('filePath',globalArray,callbackFunction);
```

consider above code because the 'globalArray' declared as global i can access inside the callback function

Comment: In your example `globalArray` is an argument of `readFunction` and not a global variable.

Comment: but i declare the globalArray first. so it should be consider as global variable right?

Comment: No, inside of `readFunction` it's shadowed by the local variable. So, your "global" `globalArray` will not be affected by `readFunction` unless it's passed as an argument. And declaring it before `readFunction` does absolutely nothing in your example.

Comment: so if its shadowed by the 'readfunction' as local variable. then i should not able to log the 'globalArray' value to console right?. but i can able to log the value

Comment: If you refer to `console.log` inside of `callbackFunction`, then you're logging the "global" `globalArray`, because it's not shadowed there. As for `readFunction`, you're passing exactly the same `globalArray` as an argument there, but inside of the function you're still addressing a local variable. It's just the way you called `readFunction` which made it the very same array as the "global" `globalArray`.

Comment: You could create an empty array with any name whatsoever right before calling `readFunction`, regardless of where this call occurs, and pass this newly created array as the second argument to `readFunction`. Then this array (and not some global one) will be mutated (`path` will be pushed into it).

Answer (score 2):

You're right that `readJSONIntoArray` does't return anything in it's `callback`. Instead it appends new data to the second argument `array`, thus mutating it.

So, `readJSONIntoArray` was meant to be used in the following way:

```
var content = []; // empty array to accumulate data from readJSONIntoArray function
readJSONIntoArray('some directory', content, function () {
  // content is full of data now
  doSomething(content);
});
```

Though I must point out that this is not a common pattern in node.js, and that it should be avoided because it's too confusing.

In fact, there are several things in `readJSONIntoArray` implementation which were done wrong:

- functions should never mutate their arguments;
- async functions should not `throw` errors, they should return them in `callback` instead;
- any data produced by the function should also be returned in `callback`.